# Electeic field of electron in young's double slit experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is it possible to actually locate the elecric field of electron in which i behaves like a wave (for example young's double slit experiment)?

Comment: If you locate it, you lose interference.

Comment: I am asking about locating electric field.is it possible or somehow it will violate hisenberg's uncertanity principle

Comment: The electric field of the electron is the ability of the electron to emit and absorb photons.

Comment: How? Please explain it

Comment: The electric field is a classical concept. It does not exist in quantum mechanics. For example, when two electrons approach, they repulse not because they have the electric field. Instead one electron emits a virtual photon and is pushed away by the recoil. The other electron absorbs the photon and is pushed away by the impact. There is no force field involved, only exchanges of photons that carry energy and momentum. The electron does not have an electric field.